# Can I safely remove Banshee?

Tags: banshee, music-player

I prefer Clementine as my music player. I'd like to completely remove the default player (currently Banshee) and replace it with Clementine.

Can I do this, without breaking Ubuntu?

Comment: If any of these answers 'answered' your question please accept one of them!

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can remove it via the Ubuntu Software Centre, or if you prefer, via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove banshee
```

In Ubuntu, you can remove almost any software you don't like without encountering issues.

Comment: Confirm it. I removed banshee and ubuntu doesn't breaks :)

Answer (score 6):

Banshee is just an application in the Ubuntu system, so removing it will not cause a problem. you can issue the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove banshee
```

This will uninstall the program. However, the "remove" command still leaves your configuration files for most apps. If you want to truly remove it, where there will be no traces on your system you can issue the "purge" command. This would be done by issuing:

```
sudo apt-get purge banshee
```

Lastly the app Clementine will automatically put give itself a indicator applet for you to use.

Comment: The "purge" command will remove system-level configuration files for the application, but will **not** remove user-level configuration settings (i.e. those stored in the /home/user folders).

Comment: Paddy is correct, it doesn't remove user level config.

Comment: Sorry, I misrepresented what I meant in the post and see it now. It does not say what I thought it said. All fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove banshee safely from the synaptic package manager too. But I don't know what will happen to the Indicator applets music shortcuts

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the indicator will reference whatever Music application is specified in System Settings -- System Info -- Default Applications -- Music. That was the case when I changed between Rhythmbox and Banshee.

Comment: Thanks, never noticed that, it's because, neither banshee or rhythmbox fits me

Answer (score 0):

You may remove it but you do not need to. Just install Clementine. And if you like Clementine take a look at DeaDBeef too.